# Is it possible for a non-generic class contain a generic list in .NET (C# or VB.NET)?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics, c#-2.0

I'm hoping someone can assist me with understanding if/how something like this is possible.

In this scenario, imagine you are trying to model a grid like a spreadsheet or in a DB, but where the data in each column can only be of one data type.

Example:  Column 1 can only contain integers.

I created a generic class to model the column structure that looks like this:

```
public class CollectionColumn<T>
{
private string _name;
private string _displayName;

private List<T> _dataItems = new List<T>();

public string Name {
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value; }
}

public string DisplayName {
    get { return _displayName; }
    set { _displayName = value; }
}


public List<T> Items {
    get { return _dataItems; }
    set { _dataItems = value; }
}
}
```

Now what I want to do is have a container for the various columns (there could be CollectionColumn, CollectionColumn, etc.) with it's own properties, but I'm not sure how to do that where I can still access the columns and the data within them when I don't know their types.

This is a .NET 2.0 project so something like dynamic would not work, maybe a list of object?  I am also not sure if there is a way to do this with interfaces.

```
public class ColumnCollection
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string ContainerName { get; set; }

private List<CollectionColumn<T>> _columns;
public List<CollectionColumn<T>> Columns {
    get { return _columns; }
    set { _columns = value; }
}

}
```

What I want to be able to do is add various CollectionColumn's to the Columns collection of a ColumnCollection so I can have columns containing various types of data.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you really want to expose a `List<T>` like that?  Generally if a class is going to expose a class-type property, it should either (1) be regarded as identifying, rather than containing, the object to which it refers, (2) it should be a possibly-mutable reference to an immutable object, or (3) it should be an immutable reference to a possibly-mutable object.  By the look of it, your column is going to regard the contents of the `List<T>` as its own (so point 1 doesn't qualify), the reference is mutable (point 2), and a `List<T>` is mutable (point 3).

Comment: That's a dangerous pattern to follow because there's no way for an object that sets the reference to point to its own list know whether some other object will try to mutate the list referred to by that reference, nor for any object that wants to mutate the list held by that object to know whether a reference to that list is held by anything that is expecting that it won't change.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a fairly common problem. What you need to do is either declare a non-generic base class that your generic class inherits from or a non-generic interface that your generic class implements. You can then make your collection of that type.

For example,

```
public abstract class CollectionColumnBase
{
    private string _name;
    private string _displayName;

    public string Name {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public string DisplayName {
        get { return _displayName; }
        set { _displayName = value; }
    }

    public abstract object GetItemAt(int index);
}

public class CollectionColumn<T> : CollectionColumnBase
{
    private List<T> data = new List<T>();

    public overrides object GetItemAt(int index)
    {
        return data[index];
    }

    public List<T> Items
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
}

public class ColumnCollection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ContainerName { get; set; }

    private List<CollectionColumnBase> _columns;
    public List<CollectionColumnBase> Columns {
        get { return _columns; }
        set { _columns = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam.  I just made CollectionColumnBase abstract and new'ed up the List of CollectionColumnBase on ColumnCollection construction so it's never null.  Thanks again!

Comment: @jon333: Yep, you'd need to do those things. I'll modify the answer; thanks!