# Generic collection in a non-generic class

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have the following class and interface

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> where T : MyInterface
{
}

interface MyInterface {
}
```

I would like to have the following class:

```
class ContainerClass
{
    private List<MyAbstractClass<T>> actions = new List<MyAbstractClass<T>>();
}
```

Where `T` is any class that extends `MyInterface`.
The important bit is here that is do not want to add a generic parameter to the `ContainerClass` and I need the exact implementation class, not the interface, so I can't just say:

```
 private List<MyAbstractClass<MyInterface>> actions = new List<MyAbstractClass<MyInterface>>();
```

Long story short, I would like the following Java code in C#:

```
public class ContainerClass {
     private List<MyAbstractClass<? extends MyInterface>> list = new ArrayList<>();
}

abstract class MyAbstractClass<T extends MyInterface> {
    
}

interface MyInterface {
    
}
```

Is possible in C#?

EDIT:

To clarify the question, let's see the below code piece:

```
abstract class GameAction<T> where T : IGameEntity
    {
        protected T Subject;

        public GameAction(T subject)
        {
            Subject = subject;
        }

        public abstract bool Run();
    }

class ActionRunner {
      private List<GameAction<T>> actions = new List<GameAction<T>>();

      public void RunAll() {
            foreach (GameAction<T> action in actions) {
                 action.Run();
            }
      }
}
```

My goal here is to have different implementation classes of `GameAction`, each should be parameterized with different implementations of `IGameEntity`. `IGameEntity` can be considered now as marker interface (it has some methods, but they don't matter here), I just use it to enforce the type of Subject and to avoid repeated casting in the implementation classes. The member `Subject` can be anything, it can do anything in the Run method of the child classes.

Comment: No, that is not possible in C#. Do you need `MyAbstractClass` to be generic though?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023316/is-it-possible-for-a-non-generic-class-contain-a-generic-list-in-net-c-or-vb

Comment: No, not possible. C# uses declaration-site variance, rather than use-site variance. If you show what's in `MyInterface` though, I can show you how you can extract a covariant interface from `MyAbstractClass` that almost is the same as `MyAbstractClass<? extends MyInterface>`.

Comment: "I need the exact implementation class" and "do not want to add a generic parameter" is a circle you cannot square

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the question to reflect my intentions a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask for is not possible in C# because unfortunately only interfaces are allowed to have variant type parameters. As you said, in Java you would be able to declare a covariant variable, but in .net, due to various design decisions, you cant.

The only choice you have is to create a new interface

```
public interface MyAbstractClassWhenInReadOnlyList<out T>
{
    T Method1();
    void Method2(out T result);
    ...
}
```

and have your MyAbstractClass implement that interface.

There are some other choices, but they boil down to this, just in various guises. **There is no way to access or use an object with a type variable without knowing the exact type that was used to construct the object**. You must have a class without a type variable to use it (This includes reflection) or have an interface with the appropriate variance.

Please be aware that this has noting to do with Java's wild-card syntax nor the use-site vs declarations site variance syntax. These are both just notations used by the two programming languages to express an idea to the type checker.

**Ultimately it comes down to static variables.**

If a method accesses the List< int >.count variable vs the List< String > variable then it better be the correct value. In Java, static variables are associated with the "raw class", eg the type "List< ? extends Object >. In C# there are two variables, one associated with each set of type parameters.

Because Interfaces are unable to have static variables, there is no way that a static variable could be access incorrectly.